# Installing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, python, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv on my Ubuntu 15.04 server. I'm using the `conda` package manager.

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`

When I try importing `cv2`, the Python package, I get the following error.

```
ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I install this dependency? I tried apt-get installing `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` but it doesn't seem to exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At least in Ubuntu 16.04, `libgtk2.0-0` contains `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`, so this works:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

Comment: it works. thanks. I spent a lot of time to get to here

Comment: BEWARE.  I only copied `apt-get install libgtk2.0-` and that removed almost all of my system.

Comment: Didn't work in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: worked on raspbian buster too