# missing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 in 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, shared-library

id got "X3: Reunion" from gog. But if I want to start it, I get the message

```
./X3R_config: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761589/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-ubuntu-15-04) but it says `libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1).`
I didn't find anything in the [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) either.

Any suggestions, how I can get the library or play the game without it?

P.S.
I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the game is 32bit. Installing `libgtk2.0-0:i386` (along with some others) solved this problem.

Comment: This didn't help me. Full reinstallation is much better as was suggested by t35.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk2.0-0
```

solve a similar problem for me

Comment: yes, this worked for me too Ubuntu 19.04 (for Zotero was working then suddenly stopped launching properly)

```./zotero -ZoteroDebug
/opt/Zotero_linux-x86_64/updates/0/updater: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```

Comment: I had this problem while attempting to run Gimp on Kubuntu 21.04, no other advice helped. But this worked for me. Gimp is running.

Comment: `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` worked on Kubuntu 22 to enable an older X app to work.